# Client load balancing in gRPC.NET

Tags: grpc, grpc-dotnet, grpc-load-balancing

Grpc.NET includes a [client-side load balancer](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-load-balancing/#client-side-lb-options) (Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer).

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/loadbalancing?view=aspnetcore-8.0) is how to use it in asp.net.

However it is not clear what the **default** behaviour is in some scenarios (and therefore how to determine when writing a custom load balancer is required).

### Failover

What happens is servers fail? Let's see a few scenarios

- round-robin: If a server fails will the future traffic automatically be sent to the survivors? In this case, will the round-robin scheme adapt to the new number of active servers? When the dead server comes back, will the load balancer automatically restore the original operations?
- pick-first: If the current server fails will the future traffic be
  automatically switched to the another of the available servers (without restarting the channel)?

### Streaming

- round-robin: is the stream of items sent by a client for a single client-streaming request distributed across all the servers, or sent to only one server?
- pick-first: if the server serving a server-streaming request fails, will the load balancer automatically re-send the streaming request to another server (transparently from a client standpoint)?

Answer (score 0):

I have found answers in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-8.0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092581/proxy-load-balancing-with-grpc-streaming-requests?rq=2).