# grpc server end pushing message to client

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm new to c++ programming of Grpc.

In the tutorial, my Grpc server side can respond to the request of client side by implementing method `handle`.

However, I want the server side to send data to client periodically. Is it possible for Grpc?

Comment: Take a look at [About push notification from Server to Client](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13894) gRPC GitHub issue and related [Is it OK to use gRPC to push data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621586/is-it-ok-to-use-grpc-to-push-data) StackOveflow discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are 4 modes in Grpc. The following web provides the sample code.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/route_guide/route_guide_client.cc