# Using a ServerStreaming rpc call for long running notifications channel

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net

I am thinking about using a gRPC service to facilitate notifications between two services. (as an aside, I will be using protobuf-net/ protobuf-net.Grpc) The intent is that the client service would establish and maintain a connection to the server service, and react to notifications over time.  In an perfect technology world where there are no network blips, no server restarts, etc the idea would be to establish this connection once and have that server streaming call live for the lifetime of the application.  Obviously in the real world we need to deal with retries, reconnects, fail-overs etc.

My question is: **Is calling a server streaming call in grpc and keeping the call open for long periods of time an appropriate use of server streaming calls, or is it an abuse of that feature?**

Comment: Yes, gRPC is a good fit for this use case. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621586/is-it-ok-to-use-grpc-to-push-data. You can read more about gRPC at https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfectly fine use case for gRPC. gRPC is designed for this kind of use.

Yes, you have to deal with reconnections or more exactly reestablishment of streams when the connection to the server dies.

Comment: I'm sure that this is somewhat use case dependent, but is it customary or preferred to set up a duplex call to provide an ACK for each notification?